# Counter-intuitive behavior of chain drive

Tags: motors, torque, moments, force-measurement

[image]

[image]

- In a chain drive system, sprocket 2 has a motor attached, sprocket 1
  is being driven.
- The blue construction is static and immobile.
- Before starting the motor, both load cells show 0 (tare).

Considering the clockwise rotation, how can it be so, that upon starting the
motor, the load-cell1 is showing constant F- (force vector pointed upwards)?
Shouldn't it be pointing downwards (F+)?

Comment: what are the load cells attached to?

Comment: Who says it's pointing upwards. Note that if that artwork isn't your own creation you need to credit the authors. This is SE policy.

Comment: Strain gages have directions of tension and compression where tension generally increases resistance.  For any beam that is bent, there is a side in tension and a side in compression.  What exactly did you measure? Where is the motor attached? What loads do the motor mounts convey to your strain gages in the load cells to satisfy Newton's third law from accelerating sprockets?

Comment: Have you considered that you are measuring the force incorrectly?

Comment: @jsotola - Load-cells are between the frame and the ground.

Comment: @Transistor - graphics is my own. Shouldn't Newton's 3rd law imply that the frame must "try" to counteract the motor-chain system direction of rotation?

Comment: @Able - the motor is mounted on the blue plate where the sprocket-2 is. The load cells are calibrated and provide correct readings with sample weights. The setup with only the Sprocket-1 rotating  (chain removed) gives the correct reading - load-cell-1 shows a positive (F+) load. Adding the chain and/or activating the motor (by i.e. manually pulling the chain in the direction of rotation) gives F- on the load-cell-1.

Comment: what is the frame connected to?

Comment: @jsotola - I have added a picture illustrating the load-cell placement

Comment: I still don't fully understand what is structurally connected to what, but the obvious thing to look at is that sprockets appear to be on different sides of the connections to load cells, meaning their moments in the same rotational direction would impose forces in different directions when slammed into the structure.

Comment: @FlegmatoidZoid is the frame connected to the  blue block in the middle of the diagram?